# Mongodb aggregation to get required objects from array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My sample document is:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "offers": [
    {
      "id": 12345,
      "amount": 100,
      "eligibleProducts": [
        111,
        123,
        156
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 12346,
      "amount": 100,
      "eligibleProducts": [
        222,
        333
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter the `offers` with `eligibleProducts`.

If my `eligibleProducts` are [111, 777, 888] then return this:

```
{
          "id": 12345,
          "amount": 100,
          "eligibleProducts": [
            111,
            123,
            156
          ]
        }
```

I used `$setIsSubset` aggregate but this is comparing with a full array,

```
"Offers" : { "$filter" : { "input" : "$Offers", "as" : "offer", "cond" : { "$and" : [{ "$setIsSubset" : {[111, 777, 888], "$$offer.eligibleProducts"]}}]}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I used $setIsSubset aggregate but this is comparing with a full array,*

The [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#definition) will not work here because, returns true when the first array is a subset of the second, including when the first array equals the second array, and false otherwise.

You can try below approach,

- `$match` are `eligibleProducts` ids in input to filter main documents
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `offers` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `eligibleProducts` array and check is id in input ids
- `$ne` to check if the above filter result is not [] empty then return object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "offers.eligibleProducts": {
        $in: [111, 777, 888]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      offers: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$offers",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$$this.eligibleProducts",
                  cond: { $in: ["$$this", [111, 777, 888]] }
                }
              },
              []
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YPBDa1Y9Flx)